# Visual CPU Indicator for Trusty Tahr (with dual/multi-core support)?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, cpu

A quick finger exercise with google returned the following:

- [`Cpufreq Indicator`](http://www.enqlu.com/2014/04/how-to-install-cpufreq-indicator-on.html)
- [`fossfreedom`](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom)'s [fork](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor) of [`System Monitor Indicator`](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor), probably looking like [this](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~alexef/store/indicator-sysmonitor.png) (non-visual)

neither of which seem to be *both*

- **visual** ("breathing"-bar-chart-like)
- multi/**dual-core compatible** (i.e., showing a bar-chart for each CPU)

<sub>I'm not after the feature of manually changing the CPU frequency (but don't mind if it ships, too).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload`

EDIT

The indicator itself will not show a bar per CPU. If you click on it though you can open gnome-system-monitor which has tab "Resources" where you can see a running per-cpu graph.